# PHP preg_match() not working

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a script I wrote to scan several websites for a google link to make sure it is there.  For some reason my script is not working. When I check it at http://www.regexr.com/, it works, but not in live implementation.

example of a link its supposed to find:

https://plus.google.com/+VincentsHeatingPlumbingIncPortHuronTownship/about?hl=en

preg_match I am using:

```
if (preg_match_all("/(.*)plus.google.com(.*)/", $attributeValue->value)) 
{ 
  $googleLinkCount ++;
  $googleLinkHrefs[] = $attributeValue->value;
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work with preg_match_all instead of the g modifier, so thanks, but that wasn't it.

Comment: switch to `m` (PCRE_MULTILINE) instead of `g` modifier

Comment: The correct answer was given below, but thanks to all of those that wanted to focus a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression, use `parse_url`:

```
if (parse_url($attributeValue->value, PHP_URL_HOST) === 'plus.google.com') {
    // host is plus.google.com
}
```